# How to set specific data in ace editor using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ace-editor

I need to set in **ace editor** this data correctly
(**myCode**):

```
<p>&lt;?php<br />// PHP code goes here<br />?&gt;</p>
```

i cant use

```
editor.setValue(myData);
```

becouse **myData** isn`t clear code (have arbitrary HTML also)

I tried this:

html

```
<div id="editor" v-html="myData">

</div>
```

js

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/php");
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by clear code?

Comment: Can you add code how have you defined `myData`.

Comment: i get code from backend

Comment: v-html dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on my page

Comment: clear code = code without  arbitrary HTML (in my case)